# Asymptotic boundary conditions for differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve the following equation ($\ell\in \mathbb{N}$)
$$f''(x)+\left(1-\dfrac{\ell(\ell+1)}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}\right)f(x)=0,$$
with these two asymptotic boundary conditions (b.c.) on the function and its derivative:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f'(x)=(\ell+1)[f(x)/x],$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\frac{1}{2i}\left[e^{ix}-e^{-i(x-\ell\pi)}\right].$$

The equation
`DiffEq = f''[x] + (1 - l(l+1)/x^2 + 2/x) f[x] == 0` can be analytically solved with `DSolve`, but I do not understand how to impose these two "analytical" b.c. to get rid of the two integration constants. I mean, they are not merely "numerical" b.c. and therefore I cannot simply do something like `DSolve[{DiffEq,f[a]==b,f[c]==d},f[x],x]`, with `a,b,c,d` being some numbers.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try applying `Asymptotic` with `Assumptions -> x > 0 && l >= 0 && l ∈ Integers` to the analytical solution at `x ->0` and `x -> Infinity`.  Note, however, that I tried doing so and ran into numerous complications.

Comment: Are you only interested in symbolic solution? Also, can you add some background info? I know this is an equation appeared in separation of variable of Laplacian equation in spherical coordinates, but never see these b.c.s before.

Comment: @xzczd yes I am interested in the symbolic solution at first, in a second moment in the numerical one, though. The b.c.s are nothing but the usual one, stated in a different manner: at the origin, you want the reduced radial wavefunction to be zero, at infinity you want it to oscillate, as in the free-particle problem.
These have been taken from a paper I am studying (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.10030.pdf), but I have also simplified it a little bit... there you can find more details, but in essence, it does not change.

Answer (score 2):

```
DSolve[y''[x] + (1 - (l (l + 1))/x^2 + 2/x) y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
(*{{y[x] -> 
C[1] WhittakerM[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 l), 2 I x] + 
C[2] WhittakerW[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 l), 2 I x]}}*)
```

without any restrict for $l$ or $x$ or $y$.

This general solution offers the integration factors for matching the first requirement:

```
Table[Limit[
    D[FunctionExpand[WhittakerW[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 l), 2 I x]], x], 
    x -> 0], {l, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image: output]

```
Table[Limit[D[FunctionExpand[WhittakerM[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 l), 2 I x]], x], 
  x -> 0], {l, 1, 10, 1}]

(*{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)

Table[Limit[D[FunctionExpand[WhittakerM[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 l),2 I x]], x], 
  x -> 0], {l, -10, 0, 1}]

(*{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}*)

Table[Limit[(l + 1) FunctionExpand[
    WhittakerM[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 l),2 I x]/x], x -> 0], {l, 1, 10, 1}]

(*{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)

Table[Limit[(l + 1) FunctionExpand[
    WhittakerM[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 l),2 I x]/x], x -> 0], {l, -10, 0, 1}]

(*{ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, \
ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, \
ComplexInfinity, Indeterminate, 1}*)
```

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'\left(x\right)  =(\ell +1)\left(\frac{f (x)}{x}\right)
$$

has not the power to give more information than that l<=0 give no contribution at x==0 to the solution. This condition can be satisfied!

The asymptotic behaviour can be treated with AsymptoticDSolveValue:

```
lsol1=AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y''[x] + (1 - (l (l + 1))/x^2 + 2/x) y[x] == 
   0}, y[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: output]

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y''[x] + (1 - (l (l + 1))/x^2 + 2/x) y[x] == 
   0}, y[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image: output]

is again independent of values for x and l. But the contributions from the integration constant c[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQXxE.png) have to be discarded.

```
Table[(lsol1 /. C[2] -> 0)/x // FullSimplify, {l, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image: output]

This is already very close to the asymptotic result:

```
Table[((l + 1) lsol1 /. C[2] -> 0)/x // FullSimplify, {l, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image: output]

```
Table[(((l + 1) lsol1 /. C[2] -> 0)/x // FullSimplify) /. x -> 0, {l, 
  1, 10, 1}]

(*{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)
```

This matches already the result in the closed-form.

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f(x)  =\frac{1}{2 i}\left(e^{i x}-e^{-(i (x-\pi  \ell ))}\right).
$$

Can be solved in Mathematica with

```
FunctionExpand[WhittakerM[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 l), 2 I x]]
```

From the discussion near x==0 the parameter c[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQXxE.png)==0 solves the problem. But it got clear that this solution diverges strong to infinity.

So for the solution for very large x C[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQXxE.png) has to be zero!

To get a first impression l==1:

```
ReImPlot[{Re@
   FunctionExpand[WhittakerM[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 1), 2 I x]], (3/(
    2 I) (E^(I x) - E^(-I ( x - 1 π))))}, {x, 0, 35}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: ReImPlot of two functions under consideration]

Examples that sustain the hypothesis are

```
ReImPlot[{FunctionExpand[
   WhittakerM[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 2), 2 I x]], (30/(
    2 I) (E^(I x) - E^(-I ( x - 2 π))))}, {x, 1335, 1355}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Plot for large values for l==2]

```
ReImPlot[{FunctionExpand[
   WhittakerM[-I, 1/2 (1 + 2 3), 2 I x]], (-400/(
    2 I) (E^(I x) - E^(-I ( x - 3 \[Pi]))))}, {x, 1335, 1355}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Plot for large values for l==3]

This has close relevance to be true.

The is the Wolfram function repository https://functions.wolfram.com/ that kind of help:

[symptotic series expansions (6 formulas)](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/WhittakerM/06/02/)

From that this

[asymptotic approximation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/WhittakerM/06/02/0006/)

seems to the the most interesting:

$$
M_{\nu ,\mu }(z)\propto \Gamma (2 \mu +1) \left(\frac{e^{z/2} \left(O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)+1\right) z^{-\nu }}{\Gamma \left(\mu -\nu +\frac{1}{2}\right)}+\frac{e^{-\frac{z}{2}} \left(O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)+1\right) \left(z^{\mu +\frac{1}{2}} (-z)^{-\mu +\nu -\frac{1}{2}}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\mu +\nu +\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)/;(\left| z\right| \to \infty)
$$

With the parameters from Your question:

[image: solution match from Wolfram functions repository]

This has the two summands with the exponential function, but not the phase at first glance.

[Thanks for Your interest. Hope this provides best advances.](http://%3Cimg%20src=%22http://vg09.met.vgwort.de/na/f74b031c0fad4991b5ec0e0bf92607da%22%20width=%221%22%20height=%221%22%20alt=%22%3E)

Comment: Your conclusion, then, is that there is no solution for the problem as stated?

Comment: Wow, thank you for your deep answer! I am not understanding, though, what is your conclusion regarding the solution at infinity, especially for what regards finding the integration constant C[1].